# Typesafe columns in jOOQ subselect

Tags: java, jooq

I have code that generates a jOOQ `Select` object, which I need to use as part of a more complex query.

Something like this works:

```
Select<Record3<Long, Integer, BigDecimal>> s = getFromSomewhere();
Field<?>[] f = s.fields();

// use it in a sub-select
Select<Record2<?,?>> x = DSL.select(f[0], f[1]).from(s);
```

But now I have lost all the type information.

Is there a better way?

Comment: The Row type seems helpful, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638337/keep-type-information-of-aliased-fields-in-jooq?rq=1, but I don't know how to construct a Row from my Select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do as a workaround is create the following unsafe, but guaranteed to work helper API:

```
public static <T1, T2, T3> Row3<T1, T2, T3> row3(Select<Record3<T1, T2, T3>> select) {
    return (Row3) DSL.row(select.field(1), select.field(2), select.field(3));
}
```

Or, if you want to take bets on jOOQ's internals, this would work as well:

```
public static <T1, T2, T3> Row3<T1, T2, T3> row3(Select<Record3<T1, T2, T3>> select) {
    (Row3<T1, T2, T3>) select.fieldsRow();
}
```

The suffix `3` is needed, because without suffix, you couldn't overload different `row` methods taking different record degrees, because of generic type erasure.

This row could then indeed be used as such:

```
Select<Record3<Long, Integer, BigDecimal>> s = getFromSomewhere();
Row3<Long, Integer, BigDecimal> row = row3(s);

// use it in a sub-select
Select<Record2<Long, Integer>> x = DSL.select(row.field1(), row.field2()).from(s);
```

I'll also register this as a feature request for jOOQ 3.6.0: [#3796](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3796).